# void in C# generics?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic method that takes a request and provides a response.

```
public Tres DoSomething<Tres, Treq>(Tres response, Treq request)
{/*stuff*/}
```

But I don't always want a response for my request, and I don't always want to feed request data to get a response. I also don't want to have to copy and paste methods in their entirety to make minor changes. What I want, is to be able to do this:

```
public Tre DoSomething<Tres>(Tres response)
{
    return DoSomething<Tres, void>(response, null);
}
```

Is this feasible in some manner? It seems that specifically using void doesn't work, but I'm hoping to find something analogous.

Comment: Why not just use System.Object and do a null check in DoSomething(Tres response, Treq request)?

Comment: Note that you do need to use the return value. You can call functions like procedures. `DoSomething(x);` instead of `y = DoSomething(x);`

Comment: I think you meant to say, "Note that you do **not** need to use the return value." @OlivierJacot-Descombes

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You cannot use `void`, but you can use `object`: it is a little inconvenience because your would-be-`void` functions need to return `null`, but if it unifies your code, it should be a small price to pay.

This inability to use `void` as a return type is at least partially responsible for a split between the `Func<...>` and `Action<...>` families of generic delegates: had it been possible to return `void`, all `Action<X,Y,Z>` would become simply `Func<X,Y,Z,void>`. Unfortunately, this is not possible.

Comment: **(Joke)** And he can still return `void` from those would-be-void methods, with `return System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(void));`. It will be a boxed void, though.

Comment: As C# supports more functional programming features, you can take a look at [Unit](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext#void-isnt-a-real-type) that represents `void` in FP. And there are good reasons to use it. In F#,  still .NET, we have `unit` built-in.

Comment: @joe In those situations my go-to is to just add `public readonly struct Nothing {}` wherever it's needed.

Answer (score 108):

No, unfortunately not. If `void` were a "real" type (like [`unit` in F#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483472.aspx), for example) life would be a lot simpler in many ways. In particular, we wouldn't need both the `Func<T>` and `Action<T>` families - there'd just be `Func<void>` instead of `Action`, `Func<T, void>` instead of `Action<T>` etc.

It would also make async simpler - there'd be no need for the non-generic `Task` type at all - we'd just have `Task<void>`.

Unfortunately, that's not the way the C# or .NET type systems work...

Comment: `Unfortunately, that's not the way the C# or .NET type systems work...` You were making me hopeful that maybe things might work like that eventually. Does your last point mean that we are not likely to ever have things work that way?

Comment: @Sahuagin: I suspect not - it would be a pretty big change at this point.

Comment: Would allowing void as a type would be like allowing null as a reference?
 Another billion dollar mistake?

Comment: @stannius: No, it's more of an inconvenience than something that leads to incorrect code, I think.

Comment: Is there advantage to have Unit reference type over empty value type to represent "void"? Empty value type seems better suited to me, it carries no value and takes no space. I wonder why void wasn't implemented like this. Popping or not popping it from stack would make no difference (talking native code, in IL it might be different).

Comment: @Ondrej: I've tried using an empty struct for things before, and it ends up not being empty in the CLR... It could be special-cased, of course. Beyond that, I don't know which I'd suggest; I haven't thought about it much.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, had no idea. To my surprise,
even [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 0)] has size of one byte.

Comment: But `System.Void` is a *real* type in C# -- it just has a bunch of restrictions on how you can use it (including with generics), which is unfortunate. -- I wonder if you can still make the call using reflection.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 No, the run-time disallows it as well (it is not only the C# spec). For example, the code `typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(void))` which tries to construct a `Func<void>`, will throw when run: `ArgumentException` _The type 'System.Void' may not be used as a type argument._ The same thing happens with `MakeGenericMethod` (on `MethodInfo`).

Comment: If C# had Void as a "real" type, I disagree that making `Func<Void>` would be better than `Action`. They could have a uniform interface, but it is arguable if it would be better to leave it non-specialized.In that, I don't see how the meat of this answer answers the question.

Answer (score 29):

Here is what you can do. As @JohnSkeet said there is no unit type in C#, so make it yourself!

```
public sealed class ThankYou {
   private ThankYou() { }
   private readonly static ThankYou bye = new ThankYou();
   public static ThankYou Bye { get { return bye; } }
}
```

Now you can always use `Func<..., ThankYou>` instead of `Action<...>`

```
public ThankYou MethodWithNoResult() {
   /* do things */
   return ThankYou.Bye;
}
```

Or use something already made by the Rx team: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.unit%28v=VS.103%29.aspx

Comment: System.Reactive.Unit is a good suggestion.  As of Nov 2016, if you are interested in getting as small a piece of the Reactive framework as possible, because you aren't using anything other than the Unit class, use nuget package manager `Install-Package System.Reactive.Core`

Comment: Rename ThankYou to "KThx", and it's a winner.  ^_^
`Kthx.Bye;`

Comment: Just to check I'm not missing something.. the Bye getter doesnt add anything significant over direct access here does it?

Comment: @Andrew you don't need bye getter, unless you want to follow the spirit of C# coding, which says you should not expose bare fields

Comment: You can also return `null!` from ThankYou-returning methods, to save the one little bit of memory that  `Bye` takes if you need it

Comment: As `ThankYou` is a `class` it it use 4 or 8 bytes on the stack (as is the size of a .NET object reference) to point to the shared `Byte` instance. This can be reduced if you change `sealed class ThankYou` to `public readonly struct ThankYou`, which should then only consume 1 byte on the stack (I don't know why we can't have zero-byte sized structs in .NET...)

Comment: The code for reactive's `Unit` type can now be found [here](https://github.com/reactiveui/Pharmacist/blob/1adebdb7376a12a488c17de627d60fdaa66f33ef/src/ICSharpCode.Decompiler/Util/EmptyList.cs#L120). They have some documentation [here](https://www.reactiveui.net/api/icsharpcode.decompiler.util/unit/)

Answer (score 19):

You could simply use `Object` as others have suggested. Or `Int32` which I have seen some use. Using `Int32` introduces a "dummy" number (use `0`), but at least you can't put any big and exotic object into an `Int32` reference (structs are sealed).

You could also write you own "void" type:

```
public sealed class MyVoid
{
  MyVoid()
  {
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Don't instantiate MyVoid.");
  }
}
```

`MyVoid` references are allowed (it's not a static class) but can only be `null`. The instance constructor is private (and if someone tries to call this private constructor through reflection, an exception will be thrown at them).

---

Since value tuples were introduced (2017, .NET 4.7), it is maybe natural to use [the struct `ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple) (the 0-tuple, the non-generic variant) instead of such a `MyVoid`. Its instance has a `ToString()` that returns `"()"`, so it looks like a zero-tuple. As of the current version of C#, you cannot use the tokens `()` in code to get an instance. You can use `default(ValueTuple)` or just `default` (when the type can be inferred from the context) instead.

Comment: Another name for this would be the null object pattern (design pattern).

Comment: @Aelphaeis This concept is a little different from a null object pattern. Here, the point is just to have some type we can use with a generic. The goal with a null object pattern is to avoid writing a method that returns null to indicate a special case and instead return an actual object with appropriate default behavior.

Answer (score 8):

I like the idea by Aleksey Bykov above, but it could be simplified a bit

```
public sealed class Nothing {
    public static Nothing AtAll { get { return null; } }
}
```

As I see no apparent reason why Nothing.AtAll could not just give null

The same idea (or the one by Jeppe Stig Nielsen) is also great for usage with typed classes.

E.g. if the type is only used to describe the arguments to a procedure/function passed as an argument to some method, and it itself does not take any arguments.

(You will still need to either make a dummy wrapper or to allow an optional "Nothing". But IMHO the class usage looks nice with myClass<Nothing> )

```
void myProcWithNoArguments(Nothing Dummy){
     myProcWithNoArguments(){
}
```

or

```
void myProcWithNoArguments(Nothing Dummy=null){
    ...
}
```

Comment: The value `null` has the connotation of being a missing or absent `object` .  Having just one value for a `Nothing` means it never looks like anything else.

Comment: It's a good idea, but I agree with @LexieHankins.  I think better would be for "nothing at all" to be a unique instance of the class `Nothing` stored in a private static field and adding a private constructor.  The fact that null is still possible is annoying, but that will be solved, hopefully with C# 8.

Comment: Academically I do understand the distinction, but it would be a very special case where the distinction matters. (Imagine a function of generic nullable type, where the return of "null" is used as a special marker, e.g. as some kind of error marker)

Answer (score 3):

`void`, though a type, is only valid as a return type of a method.

There is no way around this limitation of `void`.

Answer (score 3):

What I currently do is create custom sealed types with private constructor. This is better than throwing exceptions in the c-tor because you don't have to get until runtime to figure out the situation is incorrect. It is subtly better than returning a static instance because you don't have to allocate even once. It is subtly better than returning static null because it is less verbose on the call side. The only thing the caller can do is give null.

```
public sealed class Void {
    private Void() { }
}

public sealed class None {
    private None() { }
}
```