# C# generic delegate that accept function without arguments

Tags: c#, generics

I've created a generic delegate and I want to assign to it a function without any arguments.
Is it possible?

Here is what I tried so far:

```
class Program
    {
        public delegate void TemplateDel<T>(T item);

        public static void fWriteLetters(char[] p_cLetters)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < p_cLetters.Length; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(p_cLetters[i]);
        }
        void fNoArg()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No arguments!");
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TemplateDel<char[]> l_dWriteLeters  = new TemplateDel<char[]>(fWriteLetters);
            TemplateDel<void> l_dNoArg              = new TemplateDel<void>(fWriteLetters);


        }
    }
```

the last line of code doesn't compile...

Comment: "Doesn't compile" implies an error message - what is it?  Also, should the last line not be `new TemplateDel<void>(fNoArg)` not `fwriteLetters`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11319003/815938

Comment: As a style point: don't define you're own delegate types for this. Use one of the [`Func`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx) or [`Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) delegates from the framework, they already exist for up to 16 parameters. If working with event handlers – taking (object, `EventArgs`) pairs – then use [`EventHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). As these are well known readers of your code will have a better idea what you are doing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [void in C# generics?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318973/void-in-c-sharp-generics)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it is not possible.`void` is only valid in return types.You can't use it as a type in other contexts. (except the [unsafe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx) context)

You need add another overload for your delegate.

```
public delegate void TemplateDel();
```

Or simply use an [`Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

As [Selman22](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3010968/selman22) notes in the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28277180/67392):

> No it is not possible.

But there is another way, use a lambda to throw away the argument:

```
TemplateDel<bool> l_dNoArg = new TemplateDel<bool>(_ => fWriteLetters);
```

(Using `_` as the identifier here matches F#'s wildcard – ignore this argument – syntax.)

While not helpful here, this kind of wrapper is helpful when arguments are not interested in are passed and saves writing an extra member just to ignore or re-arrange arguments.

Comment: It doesn't work...
doesn't compile:
"Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"
*And I made a mistake it's suppose to be fNoArg in the last line.

Comment: @AmitLipman That error – only certain things are valid as a statement – can only be solved in context. But there was a typo which might be related.