# Pattern for deriving from an interface with a request to an interface with a request and response

Tags: c#, inheritance

So given

```
public interface IWorker<TRequest>
{
  Task DoWork(TRequest request);
}
```

If I want to derive from this interface, but also have a response *like* this:

```
public interface IWorker<TRequest, TResponse> : IWorker<TRequest>
{
  Task<TResponse> DoWork(TRequest request);
}
```

This obviously doesn't work (and new/override is not an option).  Another *not an option* is updating the TRequest object.  The only thing I can think of is the following but it seems a bit hacky:

```
public interface IWorker<TRequest, TResponse> : IWorker<TRequest>
{
  Task DoWork(TRequest request);

  TResponse WorkResult { get; }
  // or
  Task<TResponse> WorkResult { get; }
}
```

I can't imagine this is an original question (on SO or in general programming practice), I just haven't come across this issue until now.  I need all Workers to derive from `IWorker<TRequest>` for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Would it be an option to go for something like `public interface IWorker
{ Task DoWork(IWorkerContext ctx); }` and then derive `IWorkerContext<TRequest>` and `IWorkerContext<TRequest, TResponse>` ?

Comment: Fildor the response version would change the signature of the DoWork() method of your IWorker

Comment: No it wouldn't, given IWorkerContext has TRequest and TResponse as properties, which DoWork may or may not read and/or write. So it's always `await DoWork( someContext );` regardless of whether `someContext` is actually a derived `IWorkerContext<TRequest>` or a `IWorkerContext<TRequest, TResponse>`

Comment: So the response is part of the passed in request (or context, whatever we call it, it's part of the work parameter) was not an option as I mentioned.

Comment: Much simpler, though would be to only have `public interface IWorker<TRequest, TResponse>` but allow TResponse to be some "dummytype" and be ignored. But that feels a little hacky.

Comment: That does seem to be a better option.  I started looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318973/void-in-c-sharp-generics

Comment: Yes, but what I'd do instead of for example `class MyWorker : IWorker<MyRequest, object>` as suggested in there, I'd probably have `class MyWorker : IWorker<MyRequest, IgnoreResponse>` or something like that, so to signal unambiguously this won't produce an actual Response.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it to work as you originally planned.

This example defines two workers that share an interface:

1. Accepts a string and doesn't return anything (`StringInWorker`)
2. Accepts a string and returns an int (`StringInIntOutWorker`)

However you do need to define both methods. But one can just call the other.

```
public interface IWorker<TRequest>
{
   Task DoWork(TRequest request);
}

public interface IWorker<TRequest, TResponse> : IWorker<TRequest>
{
    new Task<TResponse> DoWork(TRequest request);
}

class StringInWorker : IWorker<string>
{
    public async Task DoWork(string input)
    {
        /*
            This is where you do the actual work
        */
    }
}

class StringInIntOutWorker : IWorker<string, int>
{
    async Task IWorker<string>.DoWork(string input) 
    {
        IWorker<string,int> me = this;
        await me.DoWork(input);
    }

    async Task<int> IWorker<string,int>.DoWork(string input)
    {
        /*
            This is where you do the actual work
        */
        return 0;  //Just so our example will compile
    }
}
```

Comment: This certainly works, but now there's tribal knowledge and inner coupling between methods for each future type to require.  This wouldn't be intuitive for future developers as this builds out.  (and I mentioned in my Q)

Comment: Not sure I understand. When you implement an interface, you are forced to implement its methods. This is not "tribal knowledge" but is enforced by the compiler, as with any other interface, and is normal.

Comment: The fact the a developer has to `IWorker<string,int> me = this; await me.DoWork(input);` is tribal knowledge.  There is no intuitive way for a developer to know he must cast his own class to an interface an execute his other DoWork.  This also breaks the SOL**I**D principle as only one DoWork should really be implemented.